# having trouble converting all floats to int in pandas frame

Tags: python, pandas

```
chunk_iter = pd.read_csv(source, chunksize=3000)
for chunk in chunk_iter:
    floats = chunk.select_dtypes(include=['floating'], exclude=None)  # select only columns that are float
    notna= floats.columns[floats.notna().any()].tolist()                 # grab the name of all float cols without NaN
    floats[notna] = floats[notna].astype(int)
    print ('converted items in these {} columns to int'.format(notna))
```

This is my code, I thought it should be able to grab all the float columns and convert them to int but I am getting an error indicating there is a Nan or inf value somewhere in there.

I guess I am a bit confused because I would have thought the notna variable would find all the columns with NaNs and exclude them?

Comment: So, what will you do with the nans and inf? How should the look once converted? If you say you don't want to convert them, then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: well, what i am asking is why my way of removing the nans and infs didnt work? I thought the line in notna should have taken care of the nans but as i am getting an error it has not -- so i am obviously making a mistake but I dont quite understand it.

-- i realize i could filna or drop na for example but i am less interested in that question and more interested in this question "How to select columns that dont have NaN values" which I know exist in this csv.

Comment: The mistake here is that NaNs and inf cannot be converted to `int`.

Comment: And you shouldn't selectively convert values, this results in your columns containing mixed types, which leads to performance issues.

Comment: Right, I understand that NaN and Inf cant be int, which is why line notna= floats.columns[floats.notna().any()].tolist() is collecting the names of the columns that do not have NaNs in them. And then the next line is meant to convert only those columns that are floats and dont have NaNs in them